# Looping For in PHP (add , into array)

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

This is my code :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `member` ORDER BY Code");
$fieldNum = mysql_num_fields($query);
for($q=0; $q<$fieldNum; $q++){
    $value = "'value$q'";
    echo "$value";
    echo ",";
}
```

I want the output
`value0,value1,value2, ... ,value5`
but I got the output
`value0,value1,value2, ... ,value5,`

I want to delete a last comma, what should I do?

Comment: Does `if($q!=$fieldNum-1) echo","` work

Answer (score 7):

Simple way

```
$value = array();
for($q=0;$q<$fieldNum;$q++){
        $value [] = 'value'.$q;
      }
echo implode (',', $value);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

```
for($q=0; $q<$fieldNum; $q++){
    $value = "'value$q'";
    echo "$value";
    if ($q != $fieldNum - 1) echo ",";
}
```

Comment: up vote for attempt, but `if ($q != $fieldNum - 1)` is considered bed practice

Comment: If you move the if to before the `echo $value;`, you can do `if ($q > 0) echo ',';`

Answer (score 2):

remove echo ","
instead use:

```
if ($q=0)
    echo "$value";   
else
    echo ",$value";
```

Now you have a , at start and then always a , before your value, so it never ends with a ,
this works independently of your amount of results.

Answer (score 2):

```
for($q=0;$q<$fieldNum;$q++){
    $value = "'value$q'";
    echo "$value";

    if($q==$fieldNum-1){
     echo "";
    }else{
        echo ",";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do follwoing

```
for($q=0;$q<;$q++){
  $value = "'value$q'";
  echo "$value";
  if($q < $fieldNum-1) {
    echo ",";
  }
}
```